# ObjC: can I use property = nil instead of self.property = nil to release it?

Tags: objective-c, properties, release, dealloc

I have properties in the .h file and synthesized in .m file, I know I can release it by using:

```
self.property = nil;
```

but can I use:

```
property = nil;
```

instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This is because the `@synthesized` methods that are generated using the `retain` option (or `strong`, if you're use ARC) actually look something like this:

```
- (void)setValue:(NSString *)newValue {
    [value autorelease];
    value = [newValue retain];
}
```

Therefore, when you do `self.property = nil`, the old value will be autoreleased, and the `nil` will be retained, which does nothing at all anyway.

When you just do `iVar = nil`, you never release the object the variable previously contained, so you leak.

Of course, if you're using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), you don't have to worry about any of this. The compiler will do the work for you. In that case, `iVar = nil` will have the exact same effect as `self.iVar = nil`, though some might see it as less clear.

Comment: This is only true if you're _not_ using ARC. If you're using ARC, the object will be released even when not calling the setter method (assuming the property/ivar has an ownership qualifier of `strong`). Still, IMO, it's better to explicitly call the setter.

Comment: @Andrew That's a good point, but since you don't really have to worry about retain/release in ARC, I assumed he was using manual reference counting for this example. I guess I can edit that in anyway, though, just to be safe.

Comment: Setting the ivar to nil without using the property accessor works, but negates a key point of having properties. If you're using accessors, and you later decide you need to have something happen when you change the value of a property, all you need to do is add code to the accessor method. If you don't use accessors and want to do that, you have to hunt down every place where you directly touch the ivar.

Comment: @rickster Yes and no. There are other advantages to using properties, primarily auto-synthesized getters and setters. Even so, I agree with you completely, but that's not the point of this question. It only deals with setting them to `nil` to release them.